# Bayesian optimization Python

Tags: python, bayesian

I have to find the global maxima of the following 2D function :

```
(((sin(((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/((((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))+0.8*((sin(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))
```

I am using the library from: [fmfn/Bayesian-Optimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization)

This is my code to find the global maxima :

```
import sys
from numpy import sin
sys.path.append("./")
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

bo = BayesianOptimization(lambda x, y: (((sin(((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/((((x-8)**2+y**2)**0.5)))+0.8*((sin(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))/(((x+8)**2+y**2)**0.5))),
                         {"x": (-20,20), "y": (-20, 20)})

bo.maximize(init_points=5, n_iter=50, kappa=5)

#print global maxima
print(bo.res['max'])
```

**The global maxima found through brute force is 0.79**

This program produces a value of 0.79 though it is very inconsistent. Out of 10 runs, it gives the value only once or so. 
Is there any reason why this is happening?
I was able to see the correct output only once so far in multiple runs. 
Is there any way to fix it?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried increasing `init_points` and `n_iter`?

Comment: Also, modifying `kappa` may increase or decrease occurrences of correct results: [It has the free parameter `kappa` which control the balance between exploration and exploitation](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/master/examples/visualization.ipynb)

Comment: I have tried it but I didn't see much of a difference

Comment: Try a simpler version of the function and make sure you can find the maximum. Then increase the complexity of the function, working towards the one which is specified.